# How to find md5sum of files on remote machines by doing ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, hashsum

I am running my below shell script on machineC which gets the md5sum of my files in my PRIMARY directory in machineC itself.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/data01/primary

for entry in "$PRIMARY"/*
do
    local_md5sum=$(/usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}')
    echo $local_md5sum
done
```

As soon as I run above shell script then it prints out the md5sum of my files in machineC and it is working fine.

Now same file for which I am calculating the md5sum can be either in machineA or machineB as well so I need to do ssh on machineA and machineB and do the same md5sum on the same file and store it in `remote_md5sum` variable.

If the file is not there in machineA, then it should be there in machineB for sure and the files will be in this directory in machineA and machineB

```
/bat/test/data/snapshot/20140918
```

So I got below shell script which I am running on machineC and is also trying to find the md5sum of the files on machineA or machineB

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# folder in machineC
export PRIMARY=/data01/primary

readonly SERVERS=(machineA machineB)
export SERVERS_1=${SERVERS[0]}
export SERVERS_2=${SERVERS[1]}

export FILES_LOCATION=/bat/test/data/snapshot/20140918  

for entry in "$PRIMARY"/*
do
    # find local md5sum on machineC
    local_md5sum=$(/usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}')
    echo $local_md5sum

    # find remote md5sum of the file which will be on machineA or machineB
    remote_md5sum=$(ssh user@$SERVERS_1 /usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}' || ssh bullseye@$SERVERS_2 /usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "Remote Checksum: $remote_md5sum"

    # now compare local_md5sum and remote_md5sum
done
```

But whenever I run above shell script my ssh command fails and it doesn't store md5sum value of that file in `remote_md5sum`. Is there anything wrong in this syntax?

```sh
remote_md5sum=$(ssh user@$SERVERS_1 /usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}' || ssh user@$SERVERS_2 /usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your script and this one works now. I have added some comments inside the script to make it more understandable. Let me know if you need more help.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#The export path which we set here.
export PRIMARY=/home/ramesh

#The main for loop execution starts here. 
for entry in "$PRIMARY"/*
do
    #Get the base name of the file which we check in the remote servers.
    #Get just the filenames without the path.
    #I am going to use the filename in the remote server to check. 

    filename=$(basename "$entry")
    echo "File Name: $filename"
    #Calculate the MD5Sum locally.
    local_md5sum=$(md5sum "$entry")
    echo "Local MD5Sum: $local_md5sum"

    #Check if the file exists in server1. 
    #Otherwise I can check in the other server.

    if ssh ramesh@server1 stat /home/ramesh/'$filename' \> /dev/null 2\>\&1 then

        #I have the file in server1 and so I get the md5sum from server1.
        #I store the md5sum inside remote_md5sum variable.
        remote_md5sum=$(ssh ramesh@server1 "cd /home/ramesh/; find -name '$filename'  -exec md5sum {} \;")
    else
        #Now, I know the file is in server2 as it is not present in server1. 
        remote_file=$(ssh ramesh@server2 "cd /home/ramesh/; find -name '$filename'  -exec md5sum {} \;")
    fi
    echo "Remote MD5Sum: $remote_file"
done
```

**Testing**

I wanted to test the above script for file names with spaces as well. It works well and this is the output that I get when I execute the script.

```
File Name: file1
Local MD5Sum:  39eb72b3e8e174ed20fe66bffdc9944e  /home/ramesh/file1
Remote MD5Sum: b5fc751f836c5430b617bf90a8c4725d  ./file1

File Name: file with spaces
Local MD5Sum:  36707e275264f4ac25254e2bbe5ef041  /home/ramesh/file with spaces
Remote MD5Sum: 36707e275264f4ac25254e2bbe5ef041  ./file with spaces
```

Comment: Can you add little bit explanation what does it do? I am trying to store md5sum of file in `remote_md5sum` which is on remote servers and then compare it with `local_md5sum` not between those two remote servers.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I am not comparing the md5sum of the files in machineA and machineB. FileA will be there in machineA or machineB, and I need to compare this md5sum with local md5sum.

Comment: @user2809564, please see the updated answer and let me know if it is fine.

Comment: @Halosghost, thanks for the edit. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you never use your variable `FILES_LOCATION`. That makes it useless. Second, you cannot use `||` like that in shell.

Try something like:

```sh
entry="$FILES_LOCATION/$(basename "$entry")"

remote_md5sum=$(ssh user@$SERVERS_1 /usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}')
if [ -z $remote_md5sum ] ; then 
    remote_md5sum=$(ssh user@$SERVERS_2 /usr/bin/md5sum "$entry" | awk '{print $1}')
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Totor. Can you explain what does basename do here?

Comment: @user2809564 You're welcome. `basename` takes a full `/path/to/filename` and gives you the `filename` only. The "opposite" tool is `dirname` which keeps the path only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and easy way to do it (all commands running on "machine2" as "user1"):

```
[user1@machine2]$ cd /home/user1/src

[user1@machine2]$ ssh user1@machine1 "cd src;find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \;" | md5sum --check | grep -v "OK"
```

Change directories to match your scenario.

I picked this up somewhere on the net in 2007. It helps.